# Not an ngModule Error

Tags: angular-material

When I try to compile my code, I get the following error

```
ERROR in MatTooltipModule is not an NgModule
```

My app module imports look like this

```
import {MatSliderModule, MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material';
imports: [
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatSliderModule,
      ],
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
```